# readyState issue with HTML5 video elements on ios safari

Tags: ios, html, safari

It seems on the iPad (iOS v. 5.1.1), Safari does not keep a video element's `readyState` value according to specification.  Even while loading from the video source `readyState` equals zero.

I've made a [demonstration jsfiddle which continuously checks the video's `readyState`](http://jsfiddle.net/XEmPZ/5/).  A funny observation: the `readyState` changes only after clicking the play button.

Actually, I've expected the `readyState` to switch to a higher number during loading (as it is the case with all browsers on the desktop I've tested--including Safari.) Is there a workaround? Am I getting something wrong here?

Answer (score 6):

From the [Apple developer documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/AudioandVideoTagBasics/AudioandVideoTagBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH2-SW9):

> Note: The preload attribute is supported in Safari 5.0 and later. Safari on iOS never preloads.

According to Apple the desired behavior on a mobile device is that loading only starts after you actively request the resource so as to not waste bandwidth or battery.

Regarding your question this means that Apple is adhering to the spec. Since no preload occurs  and loading only starts after you click the play button the `readyState` is zero before that point in time.

However, the `video` tag has special events which are supposed to give more information than `readyState`.

- `onCanplay`
- `onCanplaythrough`
- `onProgress`

Again, quoting the [Apple developer library (Using DOM Events to monitor load progress)](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH3-SW4)

> Note: On the iPad, Safari does not begin downloading until the user clicks the poster or placeholder. Currently, downloads begun in this manner do not emit progress events.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'm still not getting how script-driven playback is supposed to work.  On the one hand, if you disregard the readyState and invoke .play() or access some video attributes anyway, you'll get an INVALID_STATE_ERR.  On the other hand, you can't wait for the readyState to change.

Comment: Btw, in another example, I could see the the first video frame after loading the page, so there must haven been something loaded.

Comment: The frame you saw probably was the poster image which you can assign to the video to show something. The video has special events which I added to my answer.

Comment: Well, after some research I found safari does break the specification: according to the HTML 5 specification, onCanPlay is fired if "readyState newly increased to HAVE_FUTURE_DATA or greater".

Comment: But didn't you say that `readyState` increases after clicking play. And does `canPlay` not only fire after you click play in order to load something? But this is interesting nonetheless and I too like to investigate further. Would you mind sharing the link to the section you mentioned in your question?

Comment: Here is the [canplay event](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/media-elements.html#event-media-canplay) and [how the browser is supposed to act when calling play()](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/media-elements.html#dom-media-play)

Comment: Btw, impressively prompt response of yours :-)

Comment: I just happened to be at the right place at the right time ;)

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem recently and found a solution, so I thought I'd come share it.

If you want to control your video with JavaScript, the basic pattern is to wait for the video to load, and then advance the frames with code. Something like this:

```js
// Select the video element
const video = document.querySelector("video");

// Use an animation frame to wait for it to load
let req;
function wait(){
  req = window.requestAnimationFrame(wait);

  // readyState will never reach 4 on mobile Safari...
  if (video.readyState === 4) {
    window.cancelAnimationFrame(req);
    doSomethingWithYourVideo();
  }
}
req = wait();
```

I've also seen people do this `window.setInterval` instead of `window.requestAnimationFrame`, but the basic idea is the same.

On mobile Safari, however, the `readyState` will never reach `4`, even if you set your video element to `muted`. Your video will never play.

But there is a simple fix: `video.load()`. So, this works:

```js
// Select the video element
const video = document.querySelector("video");

// Tell the browser to load the video
video.load();

// Use an animation frame to wait for it to load
let req;
function wait(){
  req = window.requestAnimationFrame(wait);

  // Now, readyState will reach 4 on mobile Safari...
  if (video.readyState === 4) {
    window.cancelAnimationFrame(req);
    doSomethingWithYourVideo();
  }
}
req = wait();
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

## In iOS mobile (no matter if safari or chrome), you need to tell the browser actively to load

```js
// example with audio
const audio = new Audio("url...");
audio.load();  // this is needed on iOS mobile

// example with video
const video = new Video("url...");
video.load();  // this is needed on iOS mobile
```

Thanks for Harry Stevens to pointing that out.