# Cordova iPad app - video stalling

Tags: javascript, html, ios, video, cordova

I'm building content for an iPad app using Cordova. Since the app has already been built and is populated by a CMS, I can't add any extensions or plugins or modules or anything to it (that seems important to mention). The content I'm building is almost entirely video-driven, basically I have a bunch of `<video>` tags that are triggered by tap events. The videos are all loaded, as I said, from the CMS, not included with the app payload itself.

Most of the time it works fine, but occasionally a video starts playing and will stall about halfway through. My video files aren't very big, they're only about 13 seconds long, ~700kb or so each.

When a video stalls, the following error is logged to the console:

```
Took background task assertion (5) for playback stall
Ending background task assertion (5) for playback stall
```

The number in brackets will vary.

I haven't got a scooby as to what this means, and I'm pretty much a complete novice when it comes to the Xcode/Cordova world – Front-end dev is my thing, but the Cordova world is new to me. I can't figure out what's causing it, it seems to be random. I'm assuming it's possibly a bitrate/bandwidth thing, but that doesn't make sense because when a video is triggered, I'm detecting it's `readystate` in order to wait for it to load in before playing, so theoretically it should be fully-loaded before it starts playing.

Any solutions or tactics to try out? I'm kind of at a loss, and the internets and googles aren't being overly helpful when searching for that particular error message.

Comment: Those errors come from deeper down the stack than the browser/WebUIView. The usual reason for them is that the network can't keep the buffer filled.

You indicate that you're using `readystate` to check preload, but this is unreliable/broken in Mobile Safari. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633929/readystate-issue-with-html5-video-elements-on-ios-safari and http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH3-SW4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is the loading, a nice trick in Cordova is trying to set it in a (small) timeOut, so that the rest gets loaded before the video. As mentioned above, the readtyState option isn't always reliable.

Comment: This seems to have sorted it. Thanks!