# Chrome video element canplay event not firing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-video

In Chrome 31 on Windows 7 and Linux (Ubuntu 13.10) an event handler on a *video* element, registered for *canplay* (and *oncanplay*, just to make sure) never fires. When I inspect the DOM node, there's no *oncanplay* property. The [spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#mediaevents) says it should exist. Does anyone have any idea when, or if, Chrome might support this event?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Chrome *does* support the `canplay` event. You're not seeing it because the inspector only shows those properties that are on all elements, not just media elements. It also does not show `loadedmetadata`, `durationchange`, etc. but Chrome definitely supports those.

I haven't seen your code, but I would guess that a likely reason that you would see the event fire (assuming you're listening for it correctly) is that you've missed the event. Unless you're skipping around the video quite a bit, `canplay` will only fire one time. So if the event fires before you attach the listener, it's too late.

Instead, you can check the state, like so...

```
//assume you've already set up the video variable to point to your video element
if (video.readyState >= video.HAVE_FUTURE_DATA) {
    console.log('video can play!');
} else {
    video.addEventListener('canplay', function () {
        console.log('video can play!');
    }, false);
}
```

(Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, you may want to attach the event listener either way. The video's `readyState` can revert back if you run out of buffered data, and `canplay` might fire again later.

Comment: Or `>= video.HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA`, if want to be sure the video is loaded far enough ahead to avoid stalling!  E.g. if you aren't going to show + play the video until it is sufficiently buffered. (Test with a slow connection to server, to see the difference between `HAVE_FUTURE_DATA` and `HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA`.)

Comment: HOWEVER, be aware that **mobile** device might NEVER "be ready":  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633929/readystate-issue-with-html5-video-elements-on-ios-safari   "Safari on iOS never preloads."

Comment: That's correct. HAVE_FUTURE_DATA corresponds to the event "canplay" and HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA corresponds to "canplaythrough"

Comment: Another option is to use the attribute `preload="auto"` as I noticed the stream would `suspend` before firing a `canPlay` event / this worked for me with a similar issue on Windows / Firefox